# I put "sudo su" .bashrc will block ssh "cmd", how to fix it without remove the code?

Tags: linux, ssh, bashrc

To facilitate my work. I add

```
cd $working_dir
sudo su
```

in `~/.bashrc` file.

then I could login as root and in my working dir.

But when I need run a command from remote through ssh, It is just blocked (seems like `su` ran and waited for an input, but I didn't get a shell).

So, the problem is:

How can I login with dir changing to working-dir and with root privilege automatically and without ssh cmd blocked?

I use `pstree -a`, blocked process tree shown as this:

```
|   `-sshd
|       `-sshd
|           `-kbash -c pstree\040-a
|               `-sudo su
|                   `-su
|                       `-kbash
```

Comment: Commands like this belong in ~/.bash_profile, you don't want change directory for every shell. Having said this, standard techniques like `case $- in (*i*) ;; (*) return ;; esac` to exit ~/.bashrc before running the su might help. The big question is when you ssh into this box do you want to be root? If so why bother logging in as a normal user and just go directly in as root?

Comment: @icarus Thanks for your magic codes, works fine for me. For your big question : my company op team manage our users(privileges). we normal user have sudo privilege without passwords, but we can only logging in as our own user, but all services under maintenance belongs to root. That's why I changed my users `.bashrc` for automatically switching root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
ssh -t root@your_server "cd /path_to_your_working_dir ; bash"
```

Note that in this case your shell must be bash.